# SOQL to get all Leads that were created on particular date or range

Tags: soql, rest-api, leads

I am trying to a REST call from java and trying to query LEAD entity to get all Leads that were created on a particular date/date range. I am unable to get working query for the same.

I am doing something like this:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(loginInstanceUrl+ "/services/data/v33.0/query?q=Select+Id+,+FirstName+,+LastName+,+Company+From+Le‌​‌​ad");
```

This gives me list of all Leads. I tried adding a where clause here something like `Where CreateDate=3/25/2015` but then query fails with `CreateDate is not a column on Lead Entity`.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: you can use the date literals in SOQL as explained with examples in this article http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: @sfdc_ninja,@VamsiKrishna
I am doing something like this

 HttpGet get = new HttpGet(loginInstanceUrl+
                "/services/data/v33.0/query?q=Select+Id+,+FirstName+,+LastName+,+Company+From+Lead");

This gives me list of all Leads. I tried adding a where clause here something like "Where CreateDate=3/25/2015" but then query fails as CreateDate is not a column on Lead Entity.

Should I use multiple query to achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: @sfdc_ninja
 I am doing something like this HttpGet get = new HttpGet(loginInstanceUrl+ "/services/data/v33.0/query?q=Select+Id+,+FirstName+,+LastName+,+Company+From+Le‌​ad"); This gives me list of all Leads. I tried adding a where clause here something like "Where CreateDate=3/25/2015" but then query fails as CreateDate is not a column on Lead Entity. Should I use multiple query to achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the field isn't CreateDate but Create**d**Date.

The following query will, in example query all leads which were created in the current year:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, company, CreatedDate 
FROM Lead 
WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR


/services/data/v29.0/query?q=SELECT+id,+firstname,+lastname,+company,+CreatedDate+FROM+Lead+WHERE+CreatedDate+=+THIS_YEAR
```

Comment: Nice catch. Her query wouldn't have worked if she had spelled it correctly, though.

Comment: I was considering that a different question :p. nothing is going to work if you're not using the correct fields.

Comment: Thank you @Adrian,@Samuel for quick help
I got the API working :)

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is incorrect. For Date fields, you want to use the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. For Datetime fields, you want to use the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'`, of course escaping your quotes as needed. Because `CreatedDate` is a Datetime field, you're pretty much stuck with ranges.

```
'WHERE CreatedDate >= '2015-03-24\'T\'00:00:00\'Z\'
AND CreatedDate <= 2015-03-24\'T\'23:59:59\'Z\''
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I found out that if you want to retrieve all dataset you should not specify `WHERE` clause, like in usual SQL query.

`/services/data/v29.0/query?q=SELECT+id,+firstname,+lastname,+company,+CreatedDate+FROM+Lead`